# Testing Controller Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.3

I have the following method for a middleware

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
  {
      /**
       * test if user is logged in User
       */
      if(!$this->auth->check())
      {
        /**
         * if user email register arbitrary User
         */
        if(!$request->has('email'))
        {
            return back()
                ->with('error', "Please submit an email address!");
        }
        $user = $this->registerUser($request->input('email'));
        /**
         * [$user register a new user and set session]
         * @var Request
         */
        $request->session()->set('user', $user);
      }

      return $next($request);
  }
```

I am new to PHPUNIT and unit/ function testing so I started with

```
public function testHasSession()
    {
      $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();
      Session::shouldReceive('get')
        ->once()
          ->with('user');
      $response = $this->middleware->handle(Request::create(route('brokerquotes.request.store'), 'POST', ['email'=> $faker->email]), function ($request) {
          return 'OK';
      });
      $this->assertResponseOK();
    }
```

but it doesn't work. How can I test that the request session was set and the controller method called when the respective route binded with the middleware is triggered...?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
public function testHasSession()
{
    $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();
    $email = $faker->email;
    $this->post(route('brokerquotes.request.store'), ['email'=> $email]);
    $this->assertResponseOk();
    $this->assertEquals($email, session('user')->email);
}
```

... assuming that your user entity has a field `email`.